# Receiving an Arabic datetime error in asp.net

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar, culture

I use ADO disconnected mode to get data from database by filling dataset ds.
All data come true except the date field

```
string strDate = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["H_DT"].ToString();
```

it throws an exception says:

> Specified time is not supported in this calendar. It should be between
>   04/30/1900 00:00:00 (Gregorian date) and 11/16/2077 23:59:59
>   (Gregorian date), inclusive.

I tried to write this code

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ar-sa");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ar-sa");
```

to change the culture to Arabic but without any luck.

### Update

The following is screenshot of quick watch for the variable

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["H_DT"]` exactly? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: Soner, I edited my question with screenshot

Comment: exapnd date node also in your screen shot

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [`DateTime.ToString` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The `ToString()` method returns the string representation of the date
>   and time in the calendar used by the current culture. If the value of
>   the current `DateTime` instance is earlier than
>   `Calendar.MinSupportedDateTime` or later than
>   `Calendar.MaxSupportedDateTime`, the method throws an
>   `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Your `ar-sa` culture's default calender is [`UmAlQuraCalendar` calender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.UmAlQuraCalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar-sa");
Console.WriteLine(culture.Calendar); // prints UmAlQuraCalendar
```

And from [`UmAlQuraCalendar.MinSupportedDateTime` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.umalquracalendar.minsupporteddatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The earliest date and time supported by the UmAlQuraCalendar class,
>   which is equivalent to the first moment of **April 30, 1900 C.E. in the
>   Gregorian calendar**.

Since your `DateTime` is `1, 1, 1398`, it is too normal to throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

You can solve your problem to provide parameter an [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your `DateTime.ToString()` method which has [`GregorianCalendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by default. You can use [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example.

```
string strDate = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["H_DT"].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> I wrote globalization configuration in web config as `ar-sa` to be
>   global in all application but I faced the same error, please clarify
>   me, thanks

A `DateTime` belongs on Gregorian calendar *by default*. From [`DateTime` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx);

> Each `DateTime` member implicitly uses the Gregorian calendar to perform
>   its operation, with the exception of constructors that specify a
>   calendar, and methods with a parameter derived from `IFormatProvider`,
>   such as `System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo`, that implicitly
>   specifies a calendar.

That means your `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["H_DT"]` datetime is Gregorian calender by default. But since you using `.ToString()` method without any parameter, your method uses your `CurrentCulture` which is `ar-sa` since you wrote it in your web.config. And that culture has `UmAlQuraCalendar` calender by default. Since your datetime out of range in this calender, your code throws exception.

Remember, you have a `DateTime` with `1318` as a year in Gregorian calender, **not** `1318` as a year in `UmAlQuraCalendar` calender.

As an example;

```
var date = new DateTime(1318, 1, 1);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString(new CultureInfo("ar-sa")));
```

throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exception because it is exactly the same case of yours. This is a DateTime which is a `1318` year in a Gregorian calender, but there is no representation on `UmAlQuraCalendar` calender of this datetime because in `UmAlQuraCalendar` calender, years start with `1900` in Gregorian calender.

Take a look at how [`UmAlQuraCalendar` calender implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/umalquracalendar.cs);

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  Notes about UmAlQuraCalendar
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 /*
 **  Calendar support range:
 **      Calendar    Minimum     Maximum
 **      ==========  ==========  ==========
 **      Gregorian   1900/04/30   2077/11/17
 **      UmAlQura    1318/01/01   1500/12/30
 */
```

Comment: Thank you so much Soner, it has been resolved by your great solution,
please I need to understand something you said

"The ToString() method returns the string representation of the date and time in the calendar used by the current culture. If the value of the current DateTime instance is earlier than Calendar.MinSupportedDateTime or later than  Calendar.MaxSupportedDateTime, the method throws an  ArgumentOutOfRangeException"

I wrote globalization configuration in web config as ar-sa to be global in all application but I faced the same error, please clarify me,
thanks

Comment: and for this part 

"The earliest date and time supported by the UmAlQuraCalendar class, which is equivalent to the first moment of April 30, 1900 C.E. in the Gregorian calendar.
Since your DateTime is 1, 1, 1398, it is too normal to throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException"

date 1/1/1398 it only 38 years ago it is after 1900 Gregorian by many years

Comment: @AbrahamJosef Updated my answer with more explanation. Take a look.

Answer (score 2):

**--->cause of this issue**

the date of hijri in DateTime Object in c# is between 01/01/1318 and 30/12/1500.

in gregorian date is between years 1900 and 2077

so if we open the sql database and get the date and convert to hijri date we note that is not between the 2 hijri date above

**to make sure you can convert it by opening any converter site online**

---

**---->solutions**

**you have 2 solution to resolve this issue**

**-solusion 1**

you can update the values of date in sql

set it to real date (between 1900 and 2077)

**OR**

**-solution 2**

in your code before you get the date from datatable row you should to set the CurrentCulture to "**en**" and when you finish the code you should set the language to "**ar**".

**check the code below**

```
bool isLanguageChanged = false;
if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name == "ar")
{
    isLanguageChanged = true;

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en");
}

string dateStr = dataTable.Rows[i]["DateColumn"].ToString();

if (isLanguageChanged)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ar");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ar");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-SA");
string strDate = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["H_DT"].ToString(ci);
```

You will pass you desired culture when you are converting date to string.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `InvariantCulture` when converting dates to strings under limited cultures, just like this:

```
using System.Globalization;
string str = someDate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```