# dnn arabic language search error

Tags: dotnetnuke, arabic, dotnetnuke-9

I have a Localized dnn 9 site with two languages en-Us and ar-Sa. The english culture search works well. but the arabic one returns no result. In admin logs this error appear :
AbsoluteURL:/ar-SA/API/internalservices/searchService/search

DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke

ExceptionGUID:c85e2719-e024-4233-b65e-fb2923e7863e

AssemblyVersion:

PortalId:-1

UserId:-1

TabId:-1

RawUrl:

Referrer:

UserAgent:

ExceptionHash:AqhATE93Pt6wy2F8K3pufQbH62g=

Message:Specified time is not supported in this calendar. It should be between 04/30/1900 00:00:00 (Gregorian date) and 11/16/2077 23:59:59 (Gregorian date), inclusive. Parameter name: time

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you have a time specified somewhere (It's in a database table) that is set incorrectly, or the "culture" setting for the SA site is set up incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an Arabic calendar which is likely `UmAlQura`. Min date of this calendar is different than min date of `Gregorian` calendar.

`UmAlQura` min date is :1900/04/30
`Gregorian` min date is: 1318/01/01

Try to exclude time fields from the search. To see more info, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888711/asp-net-arabic-datetime-error).