# Specified time is not supported in this calendar ( ASP Boilerplate )

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using ASP.Net Boilerplate v3.2.4
and I have a trouble with uploading an excel file to MVC Controller by [HttpRequestBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequestbase?view=netframework-4.7.2) from Angularjs v1.7.5 using [FileUploader](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)

so, an exception was thrown when I tried to upload an excel file and the ***language of site is Arabic***, like this:

> Specified time is not supported in this calendar. It should be between
>   04/30/1900 00:00:00 (Gregorian date) and 11/16/2077 23:59:59
>   (Gregorian date), inclusive. Parameter name: time

**AppServiceBase :**

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

**Angulrjs code :**

```
 appModule.controller('usersIndex', [ 'FileUploader', function (fileUploader) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.logoUploader = new fileUploader({
            url: "User/UploadExcel",
            headers: {
                "X-XSRF-TOKEN": abp.security.antiForgery.getToken()
            },
            queueLimit: 1,
            removeAfterUpload: true
        });

        uploader.onSuccessItem = function (item, ajaxResponse, status) {
            if (ajaxResponse.success) {
                abp.message.success("success");
            } else {
                abp.message.error("error");
            }
        };

        vm.uploadLogo = function () {
            vm.logoUploader.uploadAll();
        };
    }
```

**Controller Code :**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> UploadExcel()
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count <= 0 || Request.Files[0] == null)
        {
            throw new UserFriendlyException(L("File_Empty_Error"));
        }

        var file = Request.Files[0];
        var usersList = new List<UserListDto>();

        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
        {
            var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
            var workSheet = currentSheet.First();

            usersList.Add(new UserListDto()
            {
                UserName = workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value.ToString(),
                PhoneNumber = workSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value.ToString()
            });
        }

        return Json(new AjaxResponse(usersList));
    }
```

**Contents of EXCEL :**

[image]

I tried to debugging c# code and javacript code and the exception is not from them

I appreciate any help

Thanks

**--- UPDATE ---**

**WORKAROUND :**

I found the solution for me,
I used a Dto to store data before uploading it. And it happens that this Dto contains dates, which I have not used directly but it exists.

Unfortunately, I did not find a solution to the culture problem.

Comment: Difficult to give you an answer, but I'd guess that there's a date or value in the file that is causing the error. Impossible to say without knowing the file contents.

Comment: There are no dates in the data
just UserName and Phone and EmailAddress

Comment: What about in the meta data contained in the rest of the file?

Comment: maybe, there are "Created" and "Modified" dates of file, but this meta data in any file... can it cause a problem?

Comment: Post the full stack trace.

Comment: Sounds like this problem is related to usage of Hijri/UmAlQuraCalendar. As stated in [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888711/receiving-an-arabic-datetime-error-in-asp-net), you need to parse Hijri date using `UmAlQuraCalendar` instance which is impossible to solve without seeing date value examples.

Comment: The problem appears to be related to excel file metadata
... means it's read-only data, I thought it better to delete it or ignore it but I did not find a way to do it

Comment: see this https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10672